# fullscreen overlay without body scrolling on mobile (jquery mobile)

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, overlay

I'm looking at implementing the solution here:
http://luxiyalu.com/scrolling-on-overlay/

When I test out the demo in firefox (emulating mobile), everything seems to work.

When I try to implement into my site (which uses jquery mobile), the body underneath scrolls.

The way I am approaching it for now is:

```
<body>

<div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-content">
put popup/overlay stuff here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="background-content">

<div data-role="page">
put normal page stuff here
</div>

</div> <!-- background-content-->
</body>
```

Is there something that jquery mobile does that is causing the body to scroll?  I'm surprised it works at all in the demo (without some type of fixed positioning for the body).  But I only know a little CSS so it's hard for me to troubleshoot.

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**
Wow, i can be so stupid, now i know it's never a good idea to turn your brain off and copy-paste without looking at something.

The author's page had the CSS listed as:

```
    .overlay{ 
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

        .overlay-content {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    }
```

The brackets were messed-up and so the browser wasn't interpretting the css properly.  Notice the close bracket for .overlay came after .overlay-content.

**New Problem:**
After fixing this, the overlay showed and scrolled until it hit the bottom of the overlay, then the body underneath picked-up the scrolling.  Terence-Hill's answer actually fixed that issue for me for android's built-in browser.  it stopped the body scrolling.  however, the body scroll issue still seems to be occurring 1) ios safari 2) ios app using webview 3) android app using webview.

any clue why it would work in android default browser but not the other 3?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
body:not(.hide-overlay) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

if you want smooth scrolling on ios use:

```
.overlay {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```